# Android Google translate update September 2017

Tags: google, chrome-for-android, android-versions, translate

So the latest android update to Google now automatically translates a Web pages. It allows you to either never translate page or never translate language. Thing is, I'm learning the language so I want to translate the page only when I'm not sure if what is saying! Before I could choose to either ignore the translate pop up or use it. Now it translates the pages straight away, which in some cases screws them up so I can't use the menus, even after going back to the original language. Why fix something that wasn't broken!

Answer (score 0):

Each app update generally should improve functionality/add new features or fix bug. If youre a fan of Google Translate you would've noticed that the new feature was already available in the web version. Since they're implementing this feature now in android, its not totally with bugs like the one you encountered. 
So my suggestion is that you disable the translate webpage option and activate "translate copied text" option which was available in prior update. When the need arises to translate, just copy and a poo up would should for you to translate. [This is however not as fluid as the webpage translation though ]

Hope I helped... Lemme know